WPF datagrid multi-page printing producing final page only
I have a C# WPF datagrid (dgdTransactions) inside a Grid (grdPastTransactions) with other TextBoxes (for headers and footers).  When it runs over more than one page I recreate the DataGrid's ItemsSource with only those rows that are to be printed on that page, create a FixedPage and then add that FixedPage to a Fixed Document for printing.
The code is below (showing code after calling PrintDialog).
My problem is that this produces a document of, say, 3 pages, but the document produces only the final page three times, and not pages 1, 2 and 3.  In other words, each iteration of the FixedPage appears to over-write its predecessors in the FixedDocument.
            int rowCount = dgdTransactions.Items.Count;
            int actualRowCount = rowCount - blankLines;
            int pageRowCount = 0;//Calculate number of pages based on DataGrid rows:
            int lengthPages = actualRowCount <= 28? 1 : ((int)(actualRowCount - 28) / 28) + 2;

            //Create FixedDocument
            FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
            document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth, printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight);

            //Add pages
            for (pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= lengthPages; pageNumber++)
            {
                var pageContent = new PageContent();
                var page = new FixedPage();

                //Expand PrintingGrid so that it includes all necessary datagrid rows
                grdTransactions.Height = (pageNumber == lengthPages && totalsLine) ? bdrReconciliation.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? 520 : 660 : 710;//Compensate for summary box 
                if (pageNumber == 1)
                {
                    dgdTransactions.ItemsSource = displayTransactions.Take(firstPageLines);
                }
                else
                {
                    dgdTransactions.ItemsSource = displayTransactions.Skip(firstPageLines + (firstPageLines * (pageNumber - 2))).Take(firstPageLines);
                }
                if (pageRowCount < actualRowCount || (pageRowCount >= actualRowCount && totalsLine))
                {
                    page = PrintMethods.GetFixedPage(printDlg, grdPastTransactions);

                    //Add page to document
                    PageContent page1Content = new PageContent();
                    ((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(page);
                    document.Pages.Add(page1Content);
                }
                pageRowCount += pageNumber == 1 ? Math.Min(actualRowCount, firstPageLines) : 28;
            }

            //Print document
            PrintMethods.PrintHelper.PrintNoPreview(printDlg, document);
            
            //Code to restore original window layout ...

and
public static FixedPage GetFixedPage(PrintDialog printDialog, Grid grdPastTransactions)
    {
        var page = new FixedPage();
        Thickness margin = new Thickness(0);
        var capabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);
        var pageSize = new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
        var visibleSize = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth - margin.Left - margin.Right, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight - margin.Top - margin.Bottom);
        var fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        //If the toPrint visual is not displayed on screen we neeed to measure and arrange it  
        grdPastTransactions.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        grdPastTransactions.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), grdPastTransactions.DesiredSize));
        grdPastTransactions.UpdateLayout();
        //  
        var size = grdPastTransactions.DesiredSize;
        //Will assume for simplicity the control fits horizontally on the page  
        double yOffset = 0;
        while (yOffset < size.Height)
        {
            var vb = new VisualBrush(grdPastTransactions)
            {
                Stretch = Stretch.None,
                AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left,
                AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top,
                ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
                TileMode = TileMode.None,
                Viewbox = new Rect(0, yOffset, visibleSize.Width, visibleSize.Height)
            };
            
            page.Width = pageSize.Width;
            page.Height = pageSize.Height;
            var canvas = new Canvas();
            FixedPage.SetLeft(canvas, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth);
            FixedPage.SetTop(canvas, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);
            canvas.Width = visibleSize.Width;
            canvas.Height = visibleSize.Height;
            canvas.Background = vb;
            page.Children.Add(canvas);
            yOffset += visibleSize.Height;
        }
        return page;
    }

and
 public static void PrintNoPreview(PrintDialog printDialog, FixedDocument fixedDoc)
        {
            try
            {
                printDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator, "PMM Report");
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeWrappedException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are trying to over-write an existing PDF document of the same name which is open." +
                    "\n\nPlease close the old document and try again, or save the new document with a new name.", "Save to PDF failed", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

Where am I going wrong? How can I get the FixedDocument to contain all of the pages created by the GetFixedPage method?
Example of xaml column definition:
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="clnDate" Header=" Date" Width="100" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="Date" CellStyle="{StaticResource NoTabCell}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=\{0:dd MMM yy\}}" Focusable="False"  Visibility="{Binding Details, Converter={StaticResource ValueConverterHideTextBoxAssetListing}}">
                                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueConverterReminderDate}">
                                        <Binding  Path="Reminder"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Date"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Foreground>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

This simply changes the date foreground to red if the transaction falls within a reminder period.

You are currently overwriting the VisualBrush.Visual value for all pages.
This is because all VisualBrush instances reference the same DataGrid. And because it implements Freezable the VisualBrush is able to report property changes which in this case trigger the referencing object to redraw itself using the updated VisualBrush. You need independent instances of the DataGrid and all parents that will be part of the VisualBrush. You must copy the complete visual tree of the VisualBrush.Visual value because you are modifying it while in use.
Using the VisualBrush is redundant in your scenario. Because you have to copy all elements you can add them directly to the FixedPage. Using VisualBrush had been a good idea if you were able to freeze it to prevent it from reporting the underlying changes.
Theoretically, one solution would be to call Freeze() on the brush. It depends on the referenced Visual whether the brush can be frozen or not. In the case of the DataGrid it isn't freezable (it really doesn't make sense as the DataGrid is expected to be dynamic). Even if it were possible. freezing the brush would also freeze all its child visuals. And you don't want to freeze the DataGrid as freezing would make it immutable. If the VisualBrush.Visual can be frozen then Freeze() would be the preferred solution.
Alternatively, you have to clone (serialize and then deserialize) the original visual tree. One common way is to use the XamlWriter to accomplish this. However, it has its limitations. One is that it doesn't serialize bindings.
So, you are only left with creating new instances of the DataGrid.
If you define a Style for the original DataGrid to configure it, instead of local configuration, then you can use this Style on the new DataGrid instances to replicate the configurations and look of the original.
This solution even allows you define a Style that is dedicated for printing only.
The following example assumes that such a Style is defined in App.xaml, but it could be defined anywhere. For performance reasons you should avoid using local resource dictionaries.
App.xaml
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle"
       TargetType="DataGrid">
  <Setter Property="Height"
          Value="400" />
  <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns"
          Value="False" />
  <Setter Property="RowBackground"
          Value="CornflowerBlue" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridPrintStyle" 
       TargetType="DataGrid"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}">
  <Setter Property="Height"
          Value="200" />
  <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns"
          Value="False" />
  <Setter Property="RowBackground"
          Value="Yellow" />
</Style>

MainWindow.xaml
<!-- 
  Configure the original DataGrid using a Style 
  so that it can be easily copied.
  We can then apply this or a based-on Style to comfortably configure 
  the copied DataGrid instance.
-->
<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

Below you can find your fixed and improved algorithm.
Please note how clean the code looks and how comfortable it is to read and understand if you post a complete method body instead of lose fragments like you did in your questions. Proper indentation also soothes the eyes and does not scare away users. You can use any editor that supports auto-formatting like VS Code for this.
Please don't get me wrong. This is just meant as a kind feedback.
To render the VisualBrush you should consider to use a more lightweight host element and replace the Canvas with a Border or Rectanlge.
As mentioned before, you can avoid all the overhead related to the VisualBrush by adding the copied visuals directly to the FixedPage.
The way you calculate and extract the pages can also be simplified (see below).
MainWindow.xaml.cs
private void CreateDocument()
{
  int rowCount = dgdTransactions.Items.Count;
  int actualRowCount = rowCount - blankLines;
  int pageRowCount = 0; //Calculate number of pages based on DataGrid rows:
  int lengthPages = actualRowCount <= 28 
    ? 1 
    : ((int)(actualRowCount - 28) / 28) + 2;

  FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
  document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth, printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight);

  // Add pages
  IEnumerable<object> pageSource = displayTransactions;
  for (pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= lengthPages; pageNumber++)
  {
    // Expand PrintingGrid so that it includes all necessary datagrid rows
    grdTransactions.Height = (pageNumber == lengthPages && totalsLine) 
      ? bdrReconciliation.Visibility == Visibility.Visible 
        ? 520 
        : 660 
      : 710; // Compensate for summary box 

    // Create a copy of the original DataGrid
    // to avoid modifying the same instance over and over again.
    // If you really need to print the parent Grid then you would have
    // to copy that too and replace the original DataGrid with its copy.
    DataGrid dgdTransactionsCopy = CopyDataGrid(dgdTransactions);

    // Simplify your pagination logic and improve the performance 
    // by avoiding skipping the complete collection (already visited items)
    // on every iteration. 
    // Instead, we only work on the unvisited remaining items.
    this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = pageSource.Take(firstPageLines);
    pageSource = pageSource
      .Skip(firstPageLines);

    if (pageRowCount < actualRowCount 
      || (pageRowCount >= actualRowCount && totalsLine))
    {
      FixedPage page = PrintMethods.GetFixedPage(printDlg, dgdTransactionsCopy);

      // Add page to document
      PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
      pageContent.Child = page;
      document.Pages.Add(pageContent);
    }

    pageRowCount += pageNumber == 1 
      ? Math.Min(actualRowCount, firstPageLines) 
      : 28;
  }
}

private DataGrid CopyDataGrid(DataGrid dataGrid)
{
  var dataGridPrintStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["DataGridPrintStyle"];
  var dataGridCopy = new DataGrid()
  {
    Style = dataGridPrintStyle,
  };

  if (double.IsNaN(dataGridCopy.Width))
  {
    dataGridCopy.Width = dataGrid.ActualWidth;
  }

  if (double.IsNaN(dataGridCopy.Height))
  {
    dataGridCopy.Height = dataGrid.ActualHeight;
  }

  foreach (DataGridColumn column in dataGrid.Columns)
  {
    DataGridColumn columnCopy = column switch
    {
      DataGridCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn => new DataGridCheckBoxColumn() { Header = checkBoxColumn.Header, IsThreeState = checkBoxColumn.IsThreeState, Binding = checkBoxColumn.Binding },
      DataGridBoundColumn boundColumn => new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = boundColumn.Binding, Header = boundColumn.Header },
      _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
    };

    dataGridCopy.Columns.Add(columnCopy);
  }

  return dataGridCopy;
}

public static FixedPage GetFixedPage(PrintDialog printDialog, UIElement printableElement)
{
  var page = new FixedPage();
  Thickness margin = new Thickness(0);
  var capabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);
  var pageSize = 
    new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
  var visibleSize = 
    new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth - margin.Left - margin.Right, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight - margin.Top - margin.Bottom);
     
  // If the toPrint visual is not displayed on screen we neeed to measure and arrange it  
  printableElement.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
  printableElement.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), printableElement.DesiredSize));
  printableElement.UpdateLayout();
    
  var size = printableElement.DesiredSize;
      
  // Will assume for simplicity the control fits horizontally on the page  
  double yOffset = 0;
  while (yOffset < size.Height)
  {
    //var vb = new VisualBrush(printableElement)
    //{
    //  Stretch = Stretch.None,
    //  AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left,
    //  AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top,
    //  ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
    //  TileMode = TileMode.None,
    //  Viewbox = new Rect(0, yOffset, visibleSize.Width, visibleSize.Height)
    //};

    //if (vb.CanFreeze)
    //{
    //  vb.Freeze();
    //}

    page. Width = pageSize.Width;
    page.Height = pageSize.Height;

    // Using a Rectangle or Border provides a more lightweight host 
    // for the VisualBrush than a Canvas
    //var brushCanvas = new Border()
    //{
    //  Width = visibleSize.Width,
    //  Height = visibleSize.Height,
    //  background = vb,
    //};

    // Add the copied element directly to the page
    FixedPage.SetLeft(printableElement, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth);
    FixedPage.SetTop(printableElement, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);
    _ = page.Children.Add(printableElement);
    yOffset += visibleSize.Height;
  }

  return page;
}


A slightly modified version of the preceding example that supports printing of complete screens. The only requirement is that the content is hosted as DataTemplate or that a DataTemplate that replicates the printed view area exists.
It's important to note that the DataTemplate copy must not define any code-behind as related references won't get resolved. If you need code-behind you must host the printable content in a UserControl or custom control.
All data must be provided by the DataContext and obtained via data binding.
The reason is that the cloned control is hosted in a dedicated but hidden visual tree to avoid the manipulations of the DataGrid to be visible for the user. Your current version shows the user your manipulations. Because the cloned visual tree is completely detached from the original visual tree relative bindings that use a source outside the printable content (e.g. the hosting UserControl) won't resolve as the cloned visual tree will start with the element that hosts the printable content.
The original DataContext is used to poupulate the cloned controls with the original data.
For example, given you have the following layout:
MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <TheDataModel /> <!-- It's important to use this exact instance for the cloned visual tree to preserve the state -->
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Some not printable text" />

    <StackPanel x:Name="PrintableContentHost">
      <TextBlock Text="Some printable text" />
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

Then the provided API gives you three options to host the printable content to choose from:
Option 1
Create a copy of the printable layout element tree, in this example it's the PrintableContentHost element, were the DataTemplate.DataType is the DataContext of the printable sub tree ( the TheDataModel in this case).
MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <TheDataModel /> <!-- It's important to use this exact instance for the cloned visual tree to preserve the state -->
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Some not printable text" />

    <StackPanel x:Name="OriginalPrintableContentHost">
      <TextBlock Text="Some printable text" />
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

App.xaml
<DataTemplate x:Name="PrintableContentTemplate" 
              Datatype="{x:Type TheDataModel}">
  <StackPanel x:Name="ClonedPrintableContentHost">
    <TextBlock Text="Some printable text" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridCopy" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
Size desiredContentSize = this.OriginalPrintableContentHost.RenderSize;

// Get the DataTemplate to clone the printable visual tree
var printableContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["PrintableContentTemplate"];

// The orignal DataContext (the TheDataMode instance)
object originalDataContext = this.OriginalPrintableContentHost.DataContext

// Dispose result to destroy the cloned visual tree
using VirtualVisualTreeRoot treeRootInfo = await VisualTreeCopyHelper.CreateCloneFromTemplateAsync(printableContentTemplate, desiredContentSize, originalDataContext);

// The "ClonedPrintableContentHost" StackPanel. We'll later use it to get the DataGrid. 
var contentRoot = (StackPanel)treeRootInfo.RootElement;

Option 2
Avoid the extra copy and display the printable content using a ContentControl that uses the same DataTemplate` to render the content:
App.xaml
<DataTemplate x:Name="PrintableContentTemplate" 
              Datatype="{x:Type TheDataModel}">
  <StackPanel x:Name="PrintableContentHost">
    <TextBlock Text="Some printable text" />
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <TheDataModel /> <!-- It's important to use this exact instance for the cloned visual tree to preserve the state -->
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Some not printable text" />

    <ContentControl x:Name="PrintableContentHost"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PrintableContentTemplate}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
Size desiredContentSize = this.PrintableContentHost.RenderSize;

// Get the DataTemplate to clone the printable visual tree
var printableContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["PrintableContentTemplate"];

// The orignal DataContext (the TheDataMode instance)
object originalDataContext = this.OriginalPrintableContentHost.DataContext

// Dispose result to destroy the cloned visual tree
using VirtualVisualTreeRoot treeRootInfo = await VisualTreeCopyHelper.CreateCloneFromTemplateAsync(printableContentTemplate, desiredContentSize, originalDataContext);

// The "PrintableContentHost" StackPanel. We'll later use it to get the DataGrid. 
var contentRoot = (StackPanel)treeRootInfo.RootElement;

Option 3
Use a UserControl or custom control to host the printable content:
PrintableContentHost.xaml.cs
partial class PrintableContentHost : UserControl
{  
}

PrintableContentHost.xaml
<UserControl>
  <TextBlock Text="Some printable text" />
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</UserControl>

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <TheDataModel /> <!-- It's important to use this exact instance for the cloned visual tree to preserve the state -->
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Some not printable text" />

    <PrintableContentHost x:Name="OriginalPrintableContentHost" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
// Dispose result to destroy the cloned visual tree
using VirtualVisualTreeRoot treeRootInfo = await VisualTreeCopyHelper.CreateCloneFromControlAsync(this.OriginalPrintableContentHost);

// The clone of the "OriginalPrintableContentHost" UserControl. 
// We'll later use it to get the DataGrid. 
var contentRoot = (PrintableContentHost)treeRootInfo.RootElement;

To reuse the cloned visual tree, and only update the DataGrid, we create a snapshot for each page by creating a RenderTargetBitmap.
The RenderTargetBitmap is then used as the source for the Image.Source to allow the FixedPage to render the snapshot.
To make the following exammple work, the DataGrid you want to modify must be named "DataGridCopy". Of course, you can use any name.
The example requires the printable area (in your case it's the grdPastTransactions grid) to be hosted inside a UserControl.
The modifed version looks as follows:
VirtualVisualTreeRoot.cs
public class VirtualVisualTreeRoot : IDisposable
{
  private bool disposedValue;
  private readonly Window visualTreeRoot;
  public FrameworkElement RootElement { get; }

  public VirtualVisualTreeRoot(Window visualTreeRoot, FrameworkElement virtualVisualTreeRoot)
  {
    this.visualTreeRoot = visualTreeRoot;
    this.RootElement = virtualVisualTreeRoot;
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (!this.disposedValue)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        this.visualTreeRoot.Close();
      }

      this.disposedValue = true;
    }
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }
}

VisualTreeCopyHelper.cs
public static class VisualTreeCopyHelper
{
  private static TaskCompletionSource ContentLoadedCompletionSource;

  public static async Task<VirtualVisualTreeRoot> CreateCloneFromTemplateAsync(DataTemplate template, Size contentSize, object dataContext)
  {
    if (!double.IsFinite(contentSize.Width) || !double.IsFinite(contentSize.Height))
    {
      throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(double.NaN)}, {nameof(double.PositiveInfinity)} and {nameof(double.NegativeInfinity)} are not allowed for the content size.", nameof(contentSize));
    }

    VisualTreeCopyHelper.ContentLoadedCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource();

    Window visualTreeRoot = GetVisualTreeRoot(contentSize);
    visualTreeRoot.Content = dataContext;
    visualTreeRoot.ContentTemplate = template;
    visualTreeRoot.Loaded += OnContentHostLoaded;
    visualTreeRoot.Show();
    visualTreeRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    await VisualTreeCopyHelper.ContentLoadedCompletionSource.Task;
    var templateRootElement = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visualTreeRoot, 0);
    var result = new VirtualVisualTreeRoot(visualTreeRoot, templateRootElement);

    return result;
  }

  public static async Task<VirtualVisualTreeRoot> CreateCloneFromControlAsync(Control controlToCopy)
  {
    VisualTreeCopyHelper.ContentLoadedCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource();

    var elementCopy = (FrameworkElement)Activator.CreateInstance(controlToCopy.GetType());
    elementCopy.Width = controlToCopy.ActualWidth;
    elementCopy.Height = controlToCopy.ActualHeight;
    elementCopy.Loaded += OnContentHostLoaded;

    if (controlToCopy is ContentControl contentControl 
      && contentControl.ContentTemplate is DataTemplate contentTemplate)
    {
      ((ContentControl)elementCopy).ContentTemplate = contentTemplate;
    }

    Window visualTreeRoot = GetVisualTreeRoot(new Size(double.NaN, double.NaN));
    visualTreeRoot.Content = elementCopy;
    visualTreeRoot.DataContext = controlToCopy.DataContext;
    visualTreeRoot.Show();
    visualTreeRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    await VisualTreeCopyHelper.ContentLoadedCompletionSource.Task;
    var result = new VirtualVisualTreeRoot(visualTreeRoot, elementCopy);

    return result;
  }

  private static Window GetVisualTreeRoot(Size size)
    => new Window
    {
      Width = size.Width,
      Height = size.Height,
      SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
      ShowInTaskbar = false,
      WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
      ShowActivated = false,
    };

  private static void OnContentHostLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var contentHost = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    contentHost.Loaded -= OnContentHostLoaded;
    VisualTreeCopyHelper.ContentLoadedCompletionSource.SetResult();
  }
}

MainWindow.xaml.cs
public static bool TryFindVisualChildElementByName<TChild>(
  DependencyObject parent,
  string childElementName,
  out TChild? resultElement) where TChild : FrameworkElement
{
  resultElement = null;

  if (parent == null)
  {
    return false;
  }

  if (parent is Popup popup)
  {
    parent = popup.Child;
    if (parent == null)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

    if (childElement is TChild frameworkElement)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(childElementName) || frameworkElement.Name.Equals(
        childElementName,
        StringComparison.Ordinal))
      {
        resultElement = frameworkElement;
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (TryFindVisualChildElementByName(childElement, childElementName, out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

// Entry point
private async Task CreateDocumentAsync()
{
  int rowCount = dgdTransactions.Items.Count;
  int actualRowCount = rowCount - blankLines;
  int pageRowCount = 0; //Calculate number of pages based on DataGrid rows:
  int lengthPages = actualRowCount <= 28 
    ? 1 
    : ((int)(actualRowCount - 28) / 28) + 2;

  FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
  document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth, printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight);

  // Create a copy of the original visual tree that contains the DataGrid
  // to avoid modifying the same instance over and over again.
  //
  // Dispose result to destroy the cloned visual tree
  using VirtualVisualTreeRoot treeRootInfo = await VisualTreeCopyHelper.CreateCloneFromControlAsync(this.PageContent);
  FrameworkElement contentRoot = treeRootInfo.RootElement;
  if (!TryFindVisualChildElementByName(contentRoot, "DataGridCopy", out DataGrid dataGridCopy))
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"DataTemplate does not contain a child element named 'DataGridCopy'.");
  }

  // The no-op lambda
  Action noOp = () => { };
  IEnumerable<object> pageSource = displayTransactions;
  for (pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= lengthPages; pageNumber++)
  {
    // Expand PrintingGrid so that it includes all necessary datagrid rows
    grdTransactions.Height = (pageNumber == lengthPages && totalsLine) 
      ? bdrReconciliation.Visibility == Visibility.Visible 
        ? 520 
        : 660 
      : 710; // Compensate for summary box 

    // Simplify your pagination logic and improve the performance 
    // by avoiding skipping the complete collection (already visited items)
    // on every iteration. 
    // Instead, we only work on the unvisited remaining items.
    dataGridCopy.ItemsSource = pageSource.Take(firstPageLines);
    pageSource = pageSource.Skip(firstPageLines);

    // Wait for the item containers to get rendered
    await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(noOp, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

    // Save the snapshot of the current DataGrid and context layout to a bitmap
    RenderTargetBitmap snapshotBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(1000, 1000, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    snapshotBitmap.Render(contentRoot);
    snapshotBitmap.Freeze();    

    // This if-statement looks suspicious.
    // At least consider to wrap the whole RenderTargetBitmap creation 
    // and DataGrid.ItemsSource ssignment to avoid wasting unnecessary resources
    if (pageRowCount < actualRowCount 
      || (pageRowCount >= actualRowCount && totalsLine))
    {
      var snapshot = new Image() { Source = snapshotBitmap };
      FixedPage page = PrintMethods.GetFixedPage(printDlg, snapshot);

      // Add page to document
      PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
      pageContent.Child = page;
      document.Pages.Add(pageContent);
    }

    pageRowCount += pageNumber == 1 
      ? Math.Min(actualRowCount, firstPageLines) 
      : 28;
  }
}

public static FixedPage GetFixedPage(PrintDialog printDialog, UIElement printableElement)
{
  var page = new FixedPage();
  Thickness margin = new Thickness(0);
  var capabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);
  var pageSize = 
    new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
  var visibleSize = 
    new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth - margin.Left - margin.Right, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight - margin.Top - margin.Bottom);
     
  // If the toPrint visual is not displayed on screen we neeed to measure and arrange it  
  printableElement.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
  printableElement.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), printableElement.DesiredSize));
  printableElement.UpdateLayout();
    
  var size = printableElement.DesiredSize;
      
  // Will assume for simplicity the control fits horizontally on the page  
  double yOffset = 0;
  while (yOffset < size.Height)
  {
    page. Width = pageSize.Width;
    page.Height = pageSize.Height;

    // Add the copied element directly to the page
    FixedPage.SetLeft(printableElement, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth);
    FixedPage.SetTop(printableElement, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);
    _ = page.Children.Add(printableElement);
    yOffset += visibleSize.Height;
  }

  return page;
}


That is a very generous and helpful response thank you @BionicCode.  I will take a few days to check it out but will revert ASAP.  In the meantime, you appear to be adding only the DataGrid to the page but I also have headers and footers that change (e.g. page number) - can I use the same code but create a copy of the whole Grid (grdPastTransactions) for the page instead of just the DataGrid?

No problem. Do you data binding? Do you use it to populate the printed controls with data?

Yes, @BionicCode, data binding and also much use of value converters.  An example of one xaml column is (apologies for just a snippet!) is added to my question above

Thanks. I will update my answer later when I have more time. Data binding i.e. getting all presented data from the DataContex is crucial for this

I have updated the example. It now clones every content you want. See the answer to learn about a few constraints that I wouldn't consider negative as they encourage you to improve the design.

Another awesome contribution, thank you @BionicCode. I am away for a few days but will try to implement your code suggestions next week. I’ll report back. Thanks again.
